# Swing Window is intermittently blank

Tags: java, swing

Swing GUI is intermitterntly blank here is a picture of what it looks like I made a loop to execute the code to display the GUI 5 times and the last one is blank I'm using InvokeLater to execute the GUI, I have tried without it and and it's still the same result. this is enough code to get the GUI up and running

```
    public class Main_UI extends JFrame {

    public Main_UI() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(329, 256);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ThemeUtils.setTopBar(gui, this);
    }
}
```

here is the code to `ThemeUtils.setTopBar`

```
    public static void setTopBar(JPanel jPanel, JFrame frame) {
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("X");
    JButton minimizeButton = new JButton("-");
    topPanel.add(minimizeButton);
    topPanel.add(exitButton);
    jPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, topPanel);
    new DragFeatures(topPanel, frame).setupDragFeatures();
}
```

and finally `DragFeatures` class code

```
public class DragFeatures {
    private Point compCoords;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;

    public DragFeatures(JPanel panel, JFrame frame) {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void setupDragFeatures() {
        compCoords = null;
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                compCoords = null;
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                compCoords = e.getPoint();
            }
        });
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - compCoords.x, currCoords.y - compCoords.y);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this should be enough to reproduce the error.

[image]

Comment: Calling `setVisible` before adding your content to the window can cause the API to not perform a layout pass.  If you want to keep this order, then call `invalidate` and `repaint` on the container which you're updating to trigger a layout and paint pass

Comment: Thank you for clearing me up on this issue, I was confused to why this would happen since it does not print out any sort of log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay look's like no one wanted to answer this question so I will go ahead and let you guys know what has fixed this. I called `setVisible` at the end of adding all my views, Thanks to @Madprogrammer